# could not create cudnn handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, cublas

I am trying to run this ballon segmentation model that I found on GitHub: 
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/tree/master/samples/balloon
.

It runs on my linux virtual machine but very very slowly, so I stop it after few iterations and installed tensorflow-gpu on my local windows OS, using: 
https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-tensorflow-gpu-windows-cuda-cudnn/

everything worked correctly.

But, unfortunately, I got this weird error, for which I can not find any solution on the internet:
'could not create cudnn handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED

ANY suggestion would be of great great help! I am now blocked since two days and dont know what to try now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow crashes with CUBLAS\_STATUS\_ALLOC\_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117740/tensorflow-crashes-with-cublas-status-alloc-failed)

Answer (score 1):

I find where it comes from. I actually had added two different paths in the environment variable (one for cuda 8 and one for cuda 9). deleting the one for cuda 8 remove this error!