# Why does my GPU Tensorflow crash when trying to run an additional time?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, syntax-error, spyder

I am pretty new to Tensorflow, and I am using a GPU installation in Anaconda with Spyder. I have a recurring problem across my programs where it will crash with a "Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2" after trying to run a file more than once.

Closing the original console and opening a new one sometimes allows me to run the file again without crashing, but sometimes it doesn't. Same thing with closing and opening the entire program again.

Normally, the programs work fine until I try to run any tensorflow operation, such as,

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(predict_op,...)
```

After which the program stalls until this error appears:

```
2019 20:45:10.359441: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2019 20:45:10.612655: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.253
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.22GiB
2019 20:45:10.684151: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.253
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.22GiB
2019 20:45:10.687572: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2019 20:45:11.509725: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019 20:45:11.510626: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0 1 
2019 20:45:11.511179: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0: N Y 
2019 20:45:11.511725: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 1: Y N 
2019 20:45:11.512401: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2928 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2019 20:45:11.901678: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 2928 MB memory) ‑> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2019 20:45:12.543674: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:459] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2019 20:45:13.105336: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:352] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please update to our latest version and try again. This problem should be fixed in that version.

Answer (score 0):

I probably crashes, because Tensorflow is greedy at allocating VRAM. Please see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117740/tensorflow-crashes-with-cublas-status-alloc-failed)