# "Attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support" error occurs

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu, tensorflow2.0, blas

my computer has only 1 GPU.

Below is what I get the result by entering someone's code

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0" device_type: "CPU" memory_limit: 268435456
locality {} incarnation: 16894043898758027805, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU" memory_limit: 10088284160
locality {bus_id: 1 links {}}
incarnation: 17925533084010082620
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:17:00.0, compute 
capability: 8.6"]
```

I use jupyter notebook and I run 2 kernels now.
(TensorFlow 2.6.0 and also installed CUDA and cuDNN as TensorFlow guide)

The first kernel is no problem to run my Sequential model from Keras.

But when I learn the same code in the second kernel, I got the error as below.

Attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support
[[node sequential_3/dense_21/MatMul (defined at \AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14764/3692363323.py:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7682]

Function call stack:
train_function

how can I learn multiple kernels without any problem and share them with only 1 GPU?

I am not familiar with TensorFlow 1.x.x version though.

---

I just solved this problem as below. This problem is because when keras run with gpu. It uses almost all vram. So i needed to give memory_limit for each notebook. Here is my code how i could solve it. You can just change memory_limit value.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],[tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=5120)])
  except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the benefit of community providing solution  here

> This problem is because when
> keras run with gpu, it uses almost all `vram`. So we needed to give
> `memory_limit` for each notebook as shown below
>
> ```
> gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
> if gpus:
>   try:
>     tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
>         gpus[0],[tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=5120)])
>   except RuntimeError as e:
>     print(e)
> ```
>
> (Paraphrased from MCPMH)

Comment: This didn't work for me but the answer to this did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117740/tensorflow-crashes-with-cublas-status-alloc-failed

Comment: @RobertFranklin You linked to a question rather than a particular answer.

Answer (score 17):

I had this error when trying to run a python script when a Jupyter notebook was open. Killing the notebook kernel before running the script did the trick. It seems that only one program can use the GPU in the same time.

Comment: This happened to me, having Blender open caused the same issue.